# Proof of SVD (Singular Value Decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, svd

I'm reading [this article](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/machine-learning-singular-value-decomposition-svd-principal-component-analysis-pca-1d45e885e491).

I don't understand the last sentence of the section **Proof (optional)**:

> Now, we just solve U, V and S for   $A = USV^T$   and prove the
> theorem.

It seems to me that this article suddenly jumped to the conclusion.
Do we have to calculate further?

I think I understand both $A^TAV = VS^2$ and $AA^TU = US^2$ well because I calculated them with a concrete example, like:
$$
A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 3 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 & -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How can we utilize the information from $A^TAV = VS^2$ and $AA^TU = US^2$ to prove the theorem?
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last sentence is poorly worded but is actually a summary. The few lines before have demonstrated how to find $V$, by solving for the eigen-vectors of $A^TA$, find $U$ from the eigen-vectors of $AA^T$. You know $S$ up to a sign ( since you have actually have $S^2$) and these signs are the only unknown, which you can decide by demanding $A=USV^T$

Comment: FIrstly, can we write $A^TAV=S^2V$, instead of $A^TAV=VS^2$ because I learned the definition of eigen-vectors as $A v = \lambda v$? Let me guess. In the section "SVD" and "Example", we were asked to use the eigen-vectors and eigen-values of $A^T A$ and $A A^T$ to compute SVD without having any proof. Then, after calculating $A=USV^T$ and $A^T=(USV^T)^T$, now we know $A^TAV=VS^2$ and $AA^TU=US^2$, which are equivalent to the eigen-vector definitions. That's why we can use the eigen-vectors and eigen-values of $A^T A$ and $A A^T$ to compute SVD (proven). ... Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: You cannot write $S^2$ to the left, but you can solve for each column of $V=[v_1,\cdots v_n]$ to get $A^TAv_j =s^2_j v_j$ which is what you have learned.  In the "proof" section you first _assume_ that $A=USV^T$ and then construct $V,S,U$ that are implied by this. Since you can build them ( that is, $U,V$ are truly orthonormal and $S$ is diagonal), they exist :).

Comment: I see, I found $A^TA v_{i} = \sigma_{i}^2 v_{i}$ in the text, thanks. But, I still don't get the connection and flow, sorry. Could you tell me why we needed to get $A^TAV = VS^2$ and $AA^TU = US^2$? What do they tell us? Yes, we _assume_ that $A=USV^T$. But, U and V are orthogonal and S is diagonal just because we manually built them to be so, didn't we? _We concatenate vectors uᵢ into U and vᵢ into V to form orthogonal matrices._ Also, _S is a diagonal matrix with r elements equal to the root of the positive eigenvalues of AAᵀ or Aᵀ A. The diagonal elements are composed of singular values._

Comment: Are you asking why the solution $U$ to $AA^TU=US^2$ is orthonormal? Eigenvectors of symmetric matrices are orthogonal (to be more precise, can be chosen to be orthogonal), and can be normalized to be orthogonal.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm asking if we already knew that U and V were orthonormal before the "proof" section because the author says: _Since these vectors are orthonormal, it is easy to prove that U and V obey $U^TU = I$ and $V^TV = I$_ (I should have copied up to here last time, sorry). In addition, I'm asking the reason why we calculated $A = USV^T$ and got $A^TAV = V^2$. I feel like, the author prepared a rudder for me and let me climb up to the roof, but after that, he took away the rudder. :(

Comment: Rudders are for boats, no wonder you cant get down :) The author ALSO states: "In addition, the covariance matrices that we often use in ML are in this form. Since they are symmetric, we can choose its eigenvectors to be orthonormal (perpendicular to each other with unit length) — this is a fundamental property for symmetric matrices."

Comment: Oops, my bad. Let me get down, please :) That's my point. Didn't we choose U and V to be orthonormal in the first place, way before the "proof" section? And also, S is diagonal because we got $\lambda_1 = 25, \lambda_2 = 9$ as vectors and **we manually** put them in a matrix to be diagonal, didn't we?

Comment: The calculation before the proof indeed found 2 orthonormal matrices, the proof shows that they are the specific ones needed for SVD. May I advise you that if this specific source for the  proof still confuses you ( I admit it it is not very didactic), find a different text.

Comment: Yes, let me try other sources. I'll be back with you. Thank you.